# get multiple property from a reducer in redux-immutable

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-immutable

I'm using `redux-immutable` and need to `connect()` multiple property in my component.

this is gameStore reducer initialState:

```
const initialState = Immutable.fromJS({
    isPlaying: null,
    level: 0,
    remainTime: 120,
    nextLevelUp: 40 ,
    requiredGoods: CROISSANT_CHOCOLATE,
    score: 0,
    renderingObjects : [],
})
```

and component `connect()`:

```
@connect((state) => ({
        renderingObjects: state.getIn(['gameStore', 'renderingObjects']).toJS(),
        isPlaying: state.getIn(['gameStore', 'isPlaying']).toJS(),
    }
))
```

But getting error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'toJS' of null

What's wrong with that?

Comment: Is `gameStore` null? I'd try logging it right there. I don't see `gameStore` in `initialState`. So maybe just try `state.getIn(['renderingObjects']).toJS()`.